WSO2 API Manager (wso2am-2.1.0) - Empty Response from API When the Accept Header is Passed
I'm using wso2am-2.1.0 and I've created an API calling to a particular backend endpoint. The endpoint and the API responds fine. However, when I pass the Accept:application/json header, as per requirement, the API gives an empty response with a 200 OK status code.
The backend when invoked directly without the accept header responds with an xml with the xml content type header and when invoked with the Accept:application/json header, it responds with application/octet-stream header.
A direction to resolve this issue is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.
